# Magento 2 Product duplicate generates unlimitted file

Tags: magento2, catalog, duplicate

I migrated M1 data to M2. After that on product duplication from admin process continue (loader displaying) and product images start duplication. In 30 GB space filled just after process started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is in product attribute `url_path` which has data in it came from M1, while in M2 `url_path` not used.
run following query to see it:

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id IN ( SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code IN ('url_path') AND entity_type_id = 4 ) AND entity_id = 1143
```

so two solutions:
delete entries from above table
OR
save null in this product attribute before duplicate the product. For that I had created one plugin for (Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Copier) which will save null in this attribute.
Have a look on the following PR image
[image]